# What is the "Unit Element" in a Categorical Monad?

Tags: monoid, monoidal-categories

From the wikipedia definition of a categorical monoid:

> [image]

**Question:** What is the nature of $I$? Say, in the context of **Set**?

Comment: Why did you waste your time and ours posting a graphic of part of a Wikipedia page rather than click on the link on that page to the definition of [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) that answers your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what a monoid is, you should first understand what a monoidal category is. Roughly, it's a category $C$ together with a bifunctor $\otimes : C \times C \to C$ satisfying certain associativity properties. One also requires $C$ to have a special object $I$ that acts as an identity for $\otimes$. A monoid $M$ in $C$ is one that's "closed" under $\otimes$. This is made precise by saying that $M$ should satisfy the axioms above.

Now $Set$ is made into a monoidal category by taking the functor $\otimes$ to be the Cartesian product. The identity should be any one point set (all of them are uniquely isomorphic). A monoid in $Set$ is a set $A$ together with an associative binary operation $A \times A \to A$ and an element $e \in A$ that acts as a neutral element for the binary operation (we may think of $e$ as the inclusion $\{e\} \to A$). In other words, a monoid in $Set$ is what you usually understand to be a monoid. For example, the natural numbers together with addition form a monoid.

Comment: From the categorical point of view, need $I = \{e\}$ be a subset of $A$ (when talking about a monoid in **Set**)? Or could it be any 1-element set?

Comment: Any one-element set. Then a map: $\{\cdot\}\to A$ is the equivalent of "an element of $A$."

Comment: (Category theory doesn't really have a notion of objects being subobjects of other objects.)